# ClassCastException while completing Firebase function (Uri and String) Android Java

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a *Task* method that calls the Cloud function (firebase's thing) and in an *Android* app's code while completing the `onCompleteListenner` app throws a *ClassCastException* kinda "String cannot be cast to Uri". What should I do?

Here's a needed code:

```
private Task<Uri> getProfilePicture(){
    return functions
            .getHttpsCallable("getProfilePicture")
            .call()
            .continueWith(task -> (Uri) task.getResult().getData())
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                String pfp = task.getResult().toString();
                Uri pfp2 = Uri.parse(pfp);
                setProfilePhoto(pfp2);
            });
}
```

Function's code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp()

export const getProfilePicture = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

const promise = admin.storage().bucket().file('usersPfp/aomkefQvkRQCuB66m6L9m94k9Bf1').getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-09.2441'
})

const p2 = promise.then(GetSignedUrlResponse => {
    const data = GetSignedUrlResponse[0]
    return response.send({"data": data})
})

p2.catch(error =>{
    console.log(error)
    return response.status(500).send({"error": error})
})
})
```

And an exception:

```
2020-01-19 15:41:04.150 28029-28029/com.happs.medrate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.happs.medrate, PID: 28029
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.net.Uri
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source:15)
    at com.happs.medrate.viewmodel.main.AccountFragmentViewModel.lambda$getProfilePicture$1$AccountFragmentViewModel(AccountFragmentViewModel.java:76)
    at com.happs.medrate.viewmodel.main.-$$Lambda$AccountFragmentViewModel$OKnCSppMNZTxWBSaV67HE9UL6mo.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.net.Uri
    at com.happs.medrate.viewmodel.main.AccountFragmentViewModel.lambda$getProfilePicture$0(AccountFragmentViewModel.java:74)
    at com.happs.medrate.viewmodel.main.-$$Lambda$AccountFragmentViewModel$gUAaj3fCSegHGtCnpDov7VKk9aQ.then(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:5)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `continueWith(task -> Uri.parse(task.getResult().getData()))`.

After that you don't need to parse it in `addOnCompleteListener`.